# useCallback React impacting Latest Array update deleting more than one Value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So i've been working with react js using Material React Table to add material (Edit,Delete), when i add new material the value in the table is increasing, but when i delete previous data on the tabel using useCallback function i realise it also deleting the new material that i've added to the table *note : the code was referrence to the React Material Table Documentation* i have try to find answer on the Internet but seems there is no explanation to this problem as i have try lots of way to fix it.
here is my code:

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Delete, Edit } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import { Close } from "@mui/icons-material";

import PublishedWithChangesIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PublishedWithChanges";
import "react-spinner-animated/dist/index.css";
import { getMaterials, create_bom } from "../../actions/data";
import MaterialReactTable from "material-react-table";
import InventoryIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Inventory";
import EqualizerIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Equalizer";
import FactoryIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Factory";
import BadgeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Badge";
import BreakfastDiningIcon from "@mui/icons-material/BreakfastDining";
import {
  Button,
  createTheme,
  Box,
  Tooltip,
  Autocomplete,
  ThemeProvider,
  useTheme,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle,
  IconButton,
  InputAdornment,
  TextField,
} from "@mui/material";

import { useEffect, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";

const CardCopiedBomData = (props) => {
  const Toast = Swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: "top-end",
    title: "left-gap",
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 5000,
    timerProgressBar: true,

    didOpen: (toast) => {
      toast.addEventListener("mouseenter", Swal.stopTimer);
      toast.addEventListener("mouseleave", Swal.resumeTimer);
    },
  });
  const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState({});
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(() => props.data.component);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const globalTheme = useTheme();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [valuess, setValues] = useState({});

  const usePrevious = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value; //assign the value of ref to the argument
    }, [value]); //this code will run when the value of 'value' changes
    return ref.current; //in the end, return the current ref value.
  };

  const { materials } = useSelector((state) => state.Data);
  const { message } = useSelector((state) => state.Message);
  const [TableData, setTableData] = useState(() => props.data.component);
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        accessorKey: "plant",
        header: "Plant",
        size: 20,
        enableColumnActions: false,
        enableColumnOrdering: false,
        muiTableHeadCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
        muiTableBodyCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "material",
        header: "Material",
        size: 20,
        enableColumnActions: false,
        enableColumnOrdering: false,
        muiTableHeadCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
        muiTableBodyCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "material_name",
        header: "Material Name",
        size: 30,
        enableColumnActions: false,
        enableColumnOrdering: false,
        enableSorting: false,
        muiTableHeadCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
        muiTableBodyCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "qty",
        header: "Quantity",
        enableColumnActions: false,
        enableColumnOrdering: false,
        enableSorting: false,
        size: 30,
        muiTableHeadCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
        muiTableBodyCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "uom",
        header: "UOM",
        enableColumnActions: false,
        enableColumnOrdering: false,
        enableSorting: false,
        size: 20,
        muiTableHeadCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
        muiTableBodyCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
      },
    ],
    []
  );
  const tableTheme = useMemo(
    () =>
      createTheme({
        MuiTableCell: {
          root: {
            paddingTop: 0,
            paddingBottom: 0,
            paddingRight: 0,
            "&:last-child": {
              paddingRight: 0,
              paddingLeft: 0,
            },
          },
        },
        overrides: {
          MuiTableCell: {
            root: {
              color: "grey",
              padding: "0px",
            },
          },
        },
        palette: {
          mode: globalTheme.palette.mode, //let's use the same dark/light mode as the global theme
          primary: globalTheme.palette.secondary, //swap in the secondary color as the primary for the table
          info: {
            main: "rgb(255,122,0)", //add in a custom color for the toolbar alert background stuff
          },
          background: {
            default:
              globalTheme.palette.mode === "light"
                ? "rgb(235,236,236)" //random light yellow color for the background in light mode
                : "#000", //pure black table in dark mode for fun
          },
        },
        typography: {
          button: {
            textTransform: "none", //customize typography styles for all buttons in table by default
            fontSize: "1.2rem",
          },
        },

        components: {
          MuiTooltip: {
            styleOverrides: {
              tooltip: {
                fontSize: "1.1rem", //override to make tooltip font size larger
              },
            },
          },
          MuiSwitch: {
            styleOverrides: {
              thumb: {
                color: "red", //change the color of the switch thumb in the columns show/hide menu to pink
              },
            },
          },
        },
      }),
    [globalTheme]
  );
  useEffect(
    (prev) => {
      setValues((values) => ({
        short_description: "",
        ...props.data,
      }));
      setTableData(props.data.component);
      console.log("Values", props.data);
    },
    [props.data, props.data.component]
  );
  const handleSaveRowEdits = async ({
    exitEditingMode,
    row,
    columns,
    values,
  }) => {
    if (!Object.keys(validationErrors).length) {
      TableData[row.index] = {
        ...values,
        qty: parseFloat(values.qty),
      };

      //send/receive api updates here, then refetch or update local table data for re-render
      setTableData([...TableData]);
      setValues({ ...valuess, component: TableData });

      exitEditingMode(); //required to exit editing mode and close modal
    }
  };
  const handleCreateMaterial = (value) => {
    TableData.push(value);
    setTableData([...TableData]);
    setValues({ ...valuess, component: TableData });
  };
  const closeModal = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const handleCancelRowEdits = () => {
    setValidationErrors({});
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "base_qty") {
      if (e.target.value === "" || e.target.value === null) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({ ...valuess, [name]: parseFloat(0) });
      } else {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({ ...valuess, [name]: parseFloat(value) });
      }
    } else {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      setValues({ ...valuess, [name]: value });
    }
  };
  const resetValues = () => {
    setTableData(data);

    props.closeModal();
  };

  //Create BOM
  const submitData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(create_bom(valuess))
      .then(() => {
        Toast.fire({
          icon: "success",
          title: `New SKU ${valuess.sku} Success Created✅`,
        });
        props.closeModal();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        props.closeModal();
        Toast.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: `Failed to Create New SKU: ${message} ❌`,
        });
      });
  };

  // const handleDeleteRow = useCallback(
  //   (row) => {
  //     TableData.splice(row.index, 1);
  //     setTableData([...TableData]);

  //     // setValues({ ...valuess, component: TableData });
  //   },
  //   [TableData]
  // );

  const validate = useCallback((instance) => {
    // validate as usual
    setTableData(() => [...instance]);
  }, []);
  // const handleDeleteRow = async (row) => {
  //   TableData.splice(row.index, 1);
  //   setTableData(() => [...TableData]);
  //   validate(TableData);

  //   // setValues({ ...valuess, component: TableData });
  // };
  const handleDeleteRow = useCallback(
    (row) => {
      TableData.splice(row.index, 1);
      setTableData([...TableData]);
      validate(TableData);
      // setValues({ ...valuess, component: TableData });
    },
    [TableData, validate]
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("TableData", TableData);
  }, [TableData]);
  const getDataMaterials = (e) => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (materials.length > 0 && materials[0].plant === props.data.plant) {
      setLoading(false);
      setOpen(true);
      return;
    }
    dispatch(getMaterials(props.data.plant)).then(() => {
      setLoading(false);
      setOpen(true);
      console.log("getDataMaterials SUccess");
    });
  };
  return (
    <Dialog
      style={{}}
      open={props.open}
      onClose={resetValues}
      aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
    >
      <DialogTitle
        id="form-dialog-title"
        sx={{
          position: "sticky",
        }}
      >
        Change Quantity BOM
        <IconButton
          sx={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: 8,
            right: 8,
            color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey[500],
          }}
          onClick={resetValues}
        >
          <Close />
        </IconButton>
      </DialogTitle>
      {
        <CardSelectMaterial
          columns={columns}
          open={open}
          closeModal={closeModal}
          createMaterial={handleCreateMaterial}
        />
      }

      <DialogContent dividers>
        <DialogContentText>
          Edit New SKU from SKU {props.data.sku ? props.data.sku : ""} from
          Plant {props.data.plant ? props.data.plant : ""} in The fields below:
        </DialogContentText>
        <form onSubmit={submitData}>
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            variant="standard"
            label="SKU"
            name="sku"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 2,
            }}
            value={valuess.sku}
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="text"
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <BreakfastDiningIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
            required
          />
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            variant="standard"
            label="SKU Name"
            name="sku_name"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 2,
            }}
            value={valuess.sku_name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="text"
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <BadgeIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
            required
          />
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            variant="standard"
            label="Plant"
            name="plant"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 2,
            }}
            value={valuess.plant}
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="text"
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <FactoryIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
            required
          />
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            variant="standard"
            label="Base Quantity"
            name="base_qty"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 2,
            }}
            value={valuess.base_qty}
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="number"
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <EqualizerIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
            required
          />
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            variant="standard"
            label="UOM"
            name="uom"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 2,
            }}
            value={valuess.uom}
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="text"
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <InventoryIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
            required
          />
          <TextField
            margin="normal"
            variant="standard"
            label="Short Description"
            name="short_description"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 2,
            }}
            value={valuess.short_description}
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="text"
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  {props.type ? props.type : ""}
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
            required
          />
          <div className="mt-2">
            <ThemeProvider theme={tableTheme}>
              <MaterialReactTable
                columns={columns}
                data={TableData ? TableData : []}
                enableHiding={false}
                enableColumnFilters={false}
                enableDensityToggle={false}
                enableStickyHeader
                enableClickToCopy
                enableEditing
                enableColumnOrdering
                onEditingRowSave={handleSaveRowEdits}
                onEditingRowCancel={handleCancelRowEdits}
                renderRowActions={({ row, table }) => (
                  <Box sx={{ display: "flex", gap: "1rem" }}>
                    <Tooltip arrow placement="left" title="Edit">
                      <IconButton onClick={() => table.setEditingRow(row)}>
                        <Edit />
                      </IconButton>
                    </Tooltip>
                    <Tooltip arrow placement="right" title="Delete">
                      <IconButton
                        color="error"
                        onClick={() => handleDeleteRow(row)}
                      >
                        <Delete />
                      </IconButton>
                    </Tooltip>
                  </Box>
                )}
                renderTopToolbarCustomActions={() => (
                  <Button
                    color="success"
                    size="medium"
                    sx={{
                      borderRadius: 2,
                      fontSize: "0.875rem",
                    }}
                    onClick={() => getDataMaterials()}
                    variant="outlined"
                  >
                    {loading ? `Loading...` : `Add Material`}
                  </Button>
                )}
                muiTableContainerProps={{
                  sx: { maxHeight: "500px", margin: "2px" },
                }}
                getRowId={(row) => row.id}
                muiTableHeadCellProps={{
                  align: "center",
                  sx: {
                    borderRight: " solid #e0e0e0",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    // "& .Mui-TableHeadCell-Content-Labels": {
                    //   padding: "0px",
                    // },
                    "& .MuiBox-root": {
                      paddingLeft: "0px",
                    },
                    backgroundColor: "white",

                    borderTop: " solid #e0e0e0",
                  },
                }}
                muiTableBodyCellProps={{
                  align: "center",
                  sx: {
                    borderRight: " solid #e0e0e0",
                    borderTop: " solid #e0e0e0",
                  },
                }}
                muiSelectCheckboxProps={{
                  color: "secondary",
                }}
                state={{
                  density: "compact",
                }}
                muiTableBodyProps={{
                  sx: {
                    //stripe the rows, make odd rows a darker color
                    "& td:nth-of-type(odd)": {
                      backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
                    },
                  },
                }}
              />
            </ThemeProvider>
          </div>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              sx={{
                backgroundColor: "green",
                "&:hover": {
                  backgroundColor: "green",
                },
              }}
              endIcon={<PublishedWithChangesIcon />}
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </form>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
export const CardSelectMaterial = (props) => {
  const [material, setMaterial] = useState(() =>
    props.columns.reduce((acc, column) => {
      acc[column.accessorKey ?? ""] = "";
      return acc;
    }, {})
  );
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const GroupHeader = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
    position: "sticky",
    top: "-8px",
    padding: "4px 10px",
    color: "darkslategray",
    backgroundColor: "aliceblue",
  }));
  const GroupItems = styled("ul")({
    padding: 0,
  });
  const { materials } = useSelector((state) => state.Data);

  const resetValues = () => {
    props.closeModal();
  };
  let data = materials.filter(
    (v, i, a) => a.findIndex((v2) => v2.material_name === v.material_name) === i
  );
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && material !== "" && material !== null) {
      setShow(true);
    } else {
      setShow(false);
    }
  };
  const options = data.map((option) => {
    const firstLetter = option.material_name[0].toUpperCase();

    return {
      firstLetter: /[0-9]/.test(firstLetter) ? "0-9" : firstLetter,
      ...option,
    };
  });
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    delete material["firstLetter"];
    props.createMaterial({ ...material, qty: 0, uom: "" });
    props.closeModal();
  };
  const handleSetSKU = (e) => {
    if (e !== "" && e !== null) {
      setMaterial(e);
    } else {
      setMaterial(e);
      setShow(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Dialog
      open={props.open}
      onClose={resetValues}
      aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
    >
      <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">
        Select Material for BOM
        <IconButton
          sx={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: 8,
            right: 8,
            color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey[500],
          }}
          onClick={resetValues}
        >
          <Close />
        </IconButton>
      </DialogTitle>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
        <DialogContent dividers>
          <DialogContentText>
            Select Material for new SKU from Fields Below:
          </DialogContentText>
          <Autocomplete
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
              option.value === value.value
            }
            style={{ width: "100%", color: "#ffffff", marginTop: "5px" }}
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
              handleSetSKU(newValue);
            }}
            id="grouped-demo"
            options={options.sort(
              (a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter)
            )}
            groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}
            getOptionLabel={(option, index) =>
              option.material_name +
              `, code:(${option.material})` +
              `, plant:(${option.plant})`
            }
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={(params) => {
              params.inputProps.onKeyDown = handleKeyDown;
              return <TextField {...params} label="Search by SKU" required />;
            }}
            renderGroup={(params) => (
              <ul key={params.key}>
                <li>
                  <GroupHeader>{params.group}</GroupHeader>
                  <GroupItems>{params.children}</GroupItems>
                </li>
              </ul>
            )}
          />
        </DialogContent>
      </form>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button
          type="submit"
          onClick={onSubmit}
          variant="contained"
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: "green",
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: "green",
            },
          }}
          endIcon={<PublishedWithChangesIcon />}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
export default CardCopiedBomData;
```

any help on this or any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: try this `setTableData(prev => prev.splice(row.index, 1))`